# jquerymobile how to freeze screen

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

I make an ajax call and during it I manually trigger jquerymobile's `loading animation` by calling `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()`

I want this loading animation to be modal(it is not when manually called). In other words during this animation I want to freeze whole screen (not only some buttons but all the elements should be unclickable, uneditable, unselectable)

anybody knows how to achieve this?

I know jquery-ui has a function for this but is it ok to use it in jquerymobile? I am developing an app for blackberry and iphone with phonegap. I'd prefer mobile version of it if it exists at all.

thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />

        <style>
            .modalWindow{
width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1500;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.ui-loader{
    z-index: 1501;
}
        </style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
function showModal(){
  $("body").append('<div class="modalWindow"/>');
  $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
  setTimeout('hideModal()', 2000);
}

function hideModal(){
 $(".modalWindow").remove();
  $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();

}

</script>

    </head>
        <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>Header</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <input type="button" value="Click to show modal loading window" onclick="showModal()"/>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>Footer</h1>
            </div>

        </div>

        </body> 
</html>
```

A demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/8uGpP/

The important thing to note here is to give the **`z-index` of the masking div to be higher than the `z-index` of all the html elements that you may be using in your application,but lesser than the `z-index` of loader div**.For satisfying this condition I have overridden the `z-index` of the `.ui-loader` . Just used 1500 for demo purpose since 1200 is the maximum `z-index` used within the JQM framework.

Comment: Nice work!  I'm surprised this isn't native to jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Nice solution. I used it in conjunction with $.ajax()'s `beforeSend` and `complete` to show and hide a modal spinner during my ajax call. Using it this way, it will only work if `async: true` is specified.

Comment: Hi, I am using JQM 4 (v1.4) and Jq 9 (1.9) on IE10. The showPageLoadingMsg() message is not being detected by IE10. It says that the object does not support this method.

Comment: @NavinIsrani showPageLoadingMsg() is deprecated.use loading() instead.Refer http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/loader/

Comment: Done! I got loading working.. ppl must be aware the $.mobile.loading ('show') works ONLY in "pageshow"  event and not in any other event.loading ('hide') call works in other events also.